# Allocate two global arrays in contiguous memory in C99

Tags: arrays, c, static-memory-allocation

I want to write some unit tests for a flash access module. I have

```
extern char_t _internal_flash_start[]; /**< Exported from ICF file. */
extern char_t _internal_flash_end[]; /**< Exported from ICF file. */
```

I thought that is perfect to inject my own array as flash content since in the application these symbols are provided via linker file. In my test I would like something like:

```
char_t _internal_flash_start[2048]; /**< Exported from ICF file. */
char_t _internal_flash_end[1];
```

But I need the second array to start exactly after the first one. I tried a lot but I could not get it to work for me. Is there a way to fulfill the given declaration and have consecutive arrays in memory?

[Edit 1/2021]

I need `_internal_flash_end` to be located at the address of `_internal_flash_start + sizeof(_internal_flash_start)` since the code MUST reference the arrays through these names.

Comment: Still I see no valid solution in the given answers. I need _internal_flash_end to be located at the address of _internal_flash_start + sizeof(_internal_flash_start) since the code MUST reference the arrays through these names.

Comment: Tasks like this are not usually done in C but are done by directing the linker to define the symbols or by using assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the second array to start exactly after the first one.

Form a `struct`

```
struct my_data {
  char_t _internal_flash_start[2048]; /**< Exported from ICF file. */
  char_t _internal_flash_end[1];
} x;
```

Still it is *possible* that there is padding between members: certainly unlikely with `char_t [2048]`.

An implementation specific `packed` would insure no padding.

---

A pedantic solution would create one array and use pointers to sections of it.  Yet now we have 2 pointers, not two arrays.  Their `sizeof` will differ from above.

```
char_t _internal_flash[2048+1];
char_t *_internal_flash_start = &_internal_flash[0];
char_t *_internal_flash_end   = &_internal_flash[2048];
```

---

OP adds:

> I need `_internal_flash_end` to be located at the address of `_internal_flash_start + sizeof(_internal_flash_start)` since the code MUST reference the arrays through these names.

Solvable with a `union` and `define`.   `_internal_flash_start` remains an array.

```
union {
  char_t both[2048 + 1];
  char_t start[2048];
} _internal_flash;
#define _internal_flash_start (_internal_flash.start)
#define _internal_flash_end (_internal_flash_start + sizeof _internal_flash_start)
```

Usage

```
int main() {
  printf("%p\n", _internal_flash_start);
  printf("%p\n", _internal_flash_end);
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof _internal_flash_start);
}
```

Output

```
0x10040b020
0x10040b820
2048
```

---

Should code require `_internal_flash_end` as an array and not just a pointer, use an implementation specific `packed` as available.

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) { // gcc specific
  char_t start[2048];
  char_t end[1];
} _internal_flash;
#define _internal_flash_start (_internal_flash.start)
#define _internal_flash_end   (_internal_flash.end)
```

Comment: Thanks. Well your first approach puts the two symbols in a struct. But that way I cannot access them directly by their names which of course is necessary in my scenario.
Your second approach works. Indeed, I already tried it.
It did not work for me since in my first tests I only needed the array addresses and not their content. Visual Studio optimized away the whole array and I wondered a lot why start and end had addresses just separated by 4 byte - the size of the pointer itsself.

Comment: Sorry, at first I thought it would work this way, but it does not. I get the desired arrays in my test. But the mapping to the two arrays in the production code (arrays, not pointers) does not work. Stepping to the test code I see that the array in the test code is located at different addresses from the two symbols in production code.
But I only see the symbols once in the map file. I am quite irritated.

Comment: @AlexanderStippler "But that way I cannot access them directly by their names which of course is necessary in my scenario" -- Code can access them directly with `x._internal_flash_start` and `x.internal_flash_end`.

Comment: inside the struct, of course. But what I want is use the two symbols declared in production code as external and not defined since in production code these values are provided by a linker script.
I want to create a stubbed flash area content for testing. Therefor I cannot encapsulate the names in a struct.

Comment: @AlexanderStippler Could code use 2 functions that return the address of the arrays?  The implementation of the functions would access the common `struct`.